# How to properly update observable in Angular Service?

Tags: angular, observable

I am writing a method to update Observable by calling a function in service from a component. Is this the right way to update an Observable? In the development mode, I saw that without calling 'next', it looks like the dictionary is updated properly but I learned that I need to call 'next' to notice all the subscribers. Between, I'm using async pipe in the template to receive observable updates.

In DataService:

```
private _subjectDictionary = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
subjectDictionary = this._subjectDictionary.asObservable();

updateSubjectDictionary(subject: string) {
    this._subjectDictionary.value[subject] = !this._subjectDictionary.value[subject];
    this._subjectDictionary.next(this._subjectDictionary);
}
```

In Component:

```
onSubjectClick(subject: string) {
    //update dictionary
    this.data.updateSubjectDictionary(subject);
}
```

Comment: You're mutating a shared object, that's not how to use observables at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to store a dictionary in the service and let components take information and modify the dictionary. Is there a better way to achieve this? Sorry, I'm new to Angular...